# Need to repeat the data if new data is not available in next month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having one table which is having data like below image.
[image]

and required Output is:

[image]

Explanation of Output:

If you see the project_ID 111 is having total 4 Version_id. 1st version Id's start Date is 08/05/2015 and version_ID 2's start date is 12/30/2015. So, in my database I am having missing month in between 2 version so, I ned to display those month with previous version ID and Need to continue till current year's last month (i.e. December 2017)

If you see the image for output same version id is repeated for next month till the new version_id is not available in that month.

Please help me with this one.. Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all, why did you tag MySQL? Secondly, go write some code first, we're not here to do that for you I'm afraid.

Comment: I had written a code which is works only for current year or for particular year with the help of CTE

Comment: share this code

Comment: shared the code and that works completely..@cha ..... Thanks @DavidG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine...

I was working with question since morning but I didn't got anything...So, posted the question.. But finally I got the answer as expected...

Here is my code

```
WITH mycte AS
(
  SELECT Project_ID ,CONVERT(DATE, Start_Date,102) DateValue, Version_ID
  from projects
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  project_id, dateadd(mm, 1, DateValue), Version_ID
  FROM    mycte   
  WHERE   year(DateValue)  <=  YEAR(GETDATE())
)
SELECT  project_id, month(DateValue), year(datevalue), max(Version_ID) as version_id, 
        cast(cast(year(DateValue) as varchar(4)) + 
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(month(DateValue) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +  
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST('01' AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) as date) as start_date
FROM    mycte
--where project_id = 111
group by project_id, month(DateValue), year(datevalue)
having max(year(datevalue)) <= year(getdate())


OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```